# Is it possible to use the GoogleMap/Places API to retrieve information about real time transit information?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-play-services, google-places-api, gtfs

The transit company has yet to release any schedule-related information on the trains in the area however it is possible to find real-time data on Google Maps. It would be really cool if there was some way to get that data to use for an app :D

Comment: It's probably worth specifying your location/transit company. In general though, probably not. Google maps API doesn't contain any real time data, and the data they use themselves is usually from the transit company in the form of GTFS-R

Comment: Here is a link to **Google Transit's API page**: https://developers.google.com/transit/  It's already integrated with Google Maps and I believe they are about to realize an API we can hit programmatically,  Also this : https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/#google_maps_and_live_transit_updates